# Selenium webdriver: list all elements of "input" drop down and select a different element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

With python3 Selenium ChromeDriver, on this URL:

https://www2.sgx.com/derivatives/products/chinaa50

1. How can I get the list of Contract Months. From Chrome F12, it appears this is the corresponding HTML.

   ```
   <sgx-input-select class="sgx-input" name="" label="" hint="" message=""
       placeholder="">
       <span class="sgx-input-hint-icon" style="visibility: hidden;"></span>
       <span class="sgx-input-hint"></span>
       <label class="sgx-input-select-label">
           <span
               class="sgx-input-label" style="display: none;"></span><span
               class="sgx-input-select-filter-wrapper"><input
               is="sgx-select-filter" type="text"
               class="sgx-input-control sgx-input-select-filter" name=""
               placeholder="" readonly="">
               <span
                   class="sgx-select-filter-icon" title=""></span>
           </span>
       </label>
       <div class="sgx-input-message" style="display: none;"></div>
       <sgx-select-model style="display: none;"></sgx-select-model>
   </sgx-input-select>
   ```
2. How can I select a different element from the list, which causes the adjacents widgets to reload?

The XPath of the drop down appears to be:

```
//*[@id="page-container"]/template-base/div/div/section[1]/div/sgx-widgets-wrapper/widget-derivatives-prices-and-chart/div[1]/div/div[2]/sgx-input-select
```

Is there a better XPath to refer to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more readable Xpath for the `Contract Month` drop down would be

```
//div[text()='Contract Month']//following-sibling::sgx-input-select//input
```

CSS selector for the `Contract Month` drop down `options`

```
.sgx-select-picker-list .sgx-select-picker-option label .sgx-select-picker-label
```

You gave to click on the Contact Month drop down and then find the `options` using the above identifiers. Then you can initiate a click on the options

psuedo code:

```
# Adding implicit wait 
driver.implicitly_wait(10)  

# Page has ajax loading where the dropdown loads slowly
# Adding sleep now. This has to be handled by webdriver wait
time.sleep(10)
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Contract Month']//following-sibling::sgx-input-select//input")
# On clicking the dropdown, the options loads 
dropdown.click();
options = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".sgx-select-picker-list .sgx-select-picker-option label .sgx-select-picker-label")

optionSize = len(options);

for index in range(optionSize - 1):
    dropdown.click();
    # Find the options again as click on Month will reset the options
    options =  driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".sgx-select-picker-list .sgx-select-picker-option label .sgx-select-picker-label")
    options.index(index).click()

    # Page has ajax loading where the dropdown loads slowly
    # Adding sleep now. This has to be handled by webdriver wait
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Finding element by CSS selector that you specified fails. Where do you see those 2 keywords
sgx-select-picker-list and sgx-select-picker-value

Comment: sgx-select-picker-list and sgx-select-picker-value are loaded in DOM `only after clicking on the dropdown` select. You can click the drop down and then look for the CSS provided in the developer tools console by typing `$$("sgx-select-picker-list .sgx-select-picker-option label .sgx-select-picker-label")`. I have also slightly modified the css.

Comment: 1. Finding the drop down works

2. Clicking the drop down works

3. Finding options works too.

4. in python, that 'options' webelement has no len(). and is not iterable

5. the 2nd find of 'options' does not work at all: NoSuchElementException

Comment: IN chrome, with the console open, I cannot have the drop down clicked and focus on the console to the type $$(...) you added there. Once the drop down is down, $(..) returns []

Comment: In Chrome, click on the dropdown to expand it. Then right click on one of the options and select `inspect element`. Now you will be able to type `$$("")` in the console without the dropdown closing up

Comment: `4. in python, that 'options' webelement has no len(). and is not iterable` is because I  had mentioned `find_element` instead of `find_elements`. I have edited the answer with the correct code. Also I have added sleeps() to account for page load via AJAX. This has to be implemented with web driver wait.